Tracking NodeJS "arrayBuffer" allocations
There are many options for heap profiling in NodeJS, but I'm having trouble finding anything to profile the memory returned by process.memoryUsage().arrayBuffers.
So far the only approach I've found is to "patch" Buffer.alloc, Buffer.allocUnsafe, Buffer.from to track allocations, along with FinalizationRegistry to track deallocations. However, I'm still only getting to around 30% of my "arrayBuffers" usage, and want to find the other sources of allocations.
I can try to find all the other functions allocating buffer memory, such as all the typed array constructors, but is there any better way to do this?
